# How to write the permission of a instance's user is the request.user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I write the `IsThePhysicalServerUser`?

you see my `UpdateAPIView`:

```
class PhysicalServerCustomerUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    """
    Customer's update PhysicalServer
    """
    serializer_class = CustomerUpdatePhysicalServerSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsThePhysicalServerUser]
    queryset = PhysicalServer.objects.all()
```

There I want to write a permission which is `IsThePhysicalServerUser`.

the `PhysicalServer` model is bellow:

```
class PhysicalServer(models.Model):
    """
    实体服务器
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="physical_servers", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I want the `IsThePhysicalServerUser` permission realize the PhysicalServer instance's use is the request user. How to write the permission?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the instance's user equals `request.user`:

```
class IsSuperAdminOrPhysicalServerCustomer(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    SuperUser or instance.user equals request.user
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # if you want everyone can see user info
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        # if you use Django2.0 is_authenticated(request.user) should be changed to request.user.is_authenticated
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
            # instance.user equal self or is superuser
            return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_superuser
        else:
            return False
```